# timeout handling by form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form field like this.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br>
  Your Message: <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now i will fire a alert for example (later a div notify) with a help information when the user is inactive after 5 seconds. so this work with this code:

```
<script>
$("#contact input").on("click",function(){
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
});

var myTimeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
    alert("How can i help you"); 
}, 5000);

myTimeout;
</script>
```

when the user click in each input field, the timeout was clear.

my todo now

as extended, now my intention is to push the same alert when the user stops fill out input fields or makes nothing subsequent after 10sec. I don't know how I can implement it. I hope for support. Thanks from a newbie.

Comment: Check if element has `focus` and value is empty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the below snippet:

```js
var _formFillTimeout = null,
    formFillTimeout = function() {
      if (_formFillTimeout) window.clearTimeout(_formFillTimeout);
      
      _formFillTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.alert("Don't stop filling the form!");
      }, 10000);
    };
    
$("form").on("keyup", "input, textarea", formFillTimeout);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br>
  Your Message: <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

It detects when user starts to fill the form, then alert when the interaction stops if user don't enter any content in the form's fields within 10 secs. If user doesn't stops typing, the timer keeps being refreshed. But I'm not sure if it holds all your desired interaction situations.